# GetProcessName in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, process, openprocess

I have a function with blow detail.

typedef part

```
   typedef DWORD (WINAPI *GETMODULEFILENAMEEX)(HANDLE hProcess, HMODULE hModule, LPTSTR   lpBaseName,DWORD nSize); 

   typedef BOOL (WINAPI *PFNTERMINATEPROCESS)(HANDLE hProcess,UINT uExitCode);
```

/// GetProcessName function

```
void GetProcessName(DWORD PID, PTSTR szProcessName, size_t cchSize)
{

    HMODULE lib=LoadLibrary(TEXT("Psapi.dll"));
    GetModuleFileNameEx=(GETMODULEFILENAMEEX)GetProcAddress
    (lib,"GetModuleFileNameExW");
    _tcscpy_s(szProcessName, cchSize, TEXT("---"));


    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ,
    FALSE,PID);

   if (hProcess == NULL) {
      _tcscpy_s(szProcessName, cchSize, TEXT("???"));
      return;
   }

   if (GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess,(HMODULE)0, szProcessName, cchSize) 
       == 0) {
     if (!GetProcessImageFileName(hProcess, szProcessName, cchSize)) {
         _tcscpy_s(szProcessName, cchSize, TEXT("???"));
      }
   }
   CloseHandle(hProcess);
}
```

I want use  this function in below function

```
BOOL WINAPI Hook_TerminateProcess(HANDLE hProcess,UINT uExitCode) {
  BOOL nResult=false;
  TCHAR szProcessName[MAX_PATH];


 nResult = ((PFNTERMINATEPROCESS)(PROC) g_TerminateProcess)(hProcess,uExitCode);

 GetProcessName(HandleToULong(hProcess),szProcessName,MAX_PATH); //my question here


    MessageBox(0, szProcessName  ,TEXT("My MessageBox Info"),MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);

   return(nResult);
}
```

When I call function `GetProcessName`, this must return process name but it ??? str always.
I call this function directly by PID, for example `GetProcessName(2018,szProcessName,MAX_PATH);`. 
2018 for example is a pid and it work.
I don't know why HandleToULong(hProcess) doesn't work. My `hProcess` must be a handle 
type certainly now how I fix this problem?

Comment: I'm not seeing anything here that is specific to C++...

Comment: Please clean up your post a bit(use more code tags!), as it looks horrible, and is a mission to read.

Answer (score 1):

char name[MAX_PATH * 2 ] = "\0", *p;

GetModuleFileName(GetModuleHandle(NULL),name,MAX_PATH);

p = name  + strlen(name) - 1;

while (isalnum(*p) || ('.' == *p) || ('_' == *p)) 
   p--;

p++;

std::cout << p << std::endl;

Comment: Seems not necessary to call GetModuleHandle at all, if the first param is NULL, it's the executable of the current process. Check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You must call [`GetProcessId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683215%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) rather than `HandleToULong`. You need a process ID, not a handle-converted-to-an-unsigned-long

Comment: of curse .thank you but again  dont work and return ??? str
how i show hProcess value in message box .maybe it haven't correct value

Comment: You're calling GetProcessName AFTER g_TerminateProcess. In which case, the process probably no longer exists, so you can't open the handle. Try switching the calls round.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, a process ID is different from a process handle.  You are taking the process handle in `Hook_TerminateProcess` and passing it into `GetProcessName` as a process ID.  This will never work.

You should refactor `GetProcessName` to take a handle and then have an overload that takes a process ID.  The process ID overload does the `OpenProcess` work to convert it into a handle and the `CloseHandle` work to clean it up.

After the refactoring, you'll have two methods:

```
void GetProcessName(HANDLE hProcess, PTSTR szProcessName, size_t cchSize);
void GetProcessName(DWORD PID, PTSTR szProcessName, size_t cchSize);
```

Comment: Hook_TerminateProcess is instead of  TerminateProcess winapi orginal function and this prototype is  TerminateProcess(HANDLE hProcess,UINT uExitCode);
now i have to pass hProcess with type of Handle  to OpenProcess that give a pid with type of DWORD
when i convert HANDLE to DWORD with func HAndletoulong it dont work
and i cant retrive processname for my decision?

in other hand i want to get process name with a pid of type Handle that terminateprocess gave to me.

Comment: Yes, you can convert a HANDLE to a DWORD with `HandleToULong`, but ***a handle is not a process ID***.  Just because you can cast data doesn't mean it's correct.  Please read my answer again.  Remove the `OpenProcess` call and just have the process handle be the parameter to the method (instead of the process ID).  If you need to pass a process ID in from somewhere else, create another method to call `OpenProcess` first to get a valid handle.

Comment: i refactor it but again dont work
Anthony Williams told me use GetProcessId instead of HandletoUlong and pass hProcess(process handle) to PID(process id)  but i dont know why openprocess return NULL how i show hProcess value in message box .maybe it haven't correct value

Answer (score 0):

1. How can you terminate the process then expect the handle to still be valid? cause if any clean up is performed, all data is lost(you don't explicitly copy the handle, so this can happen)
2. your error seems to stem from where your retrieving hProcess, in which case you should check GetLastError to see why its failing

Comment: i placed nResult = ((PFNTERMINATEPROCESS)(PROC) g_TerminateProcess)(hProcess,uExitCode);  after  MessageBox but again i dont word i mean 
getprocess name return ??? str again